# Type checking in pycharm for class-decorated property

Tags: python, pycharm, python-decorators, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm using PyCharm 2023.2.3 (Community Edition) for developing.
There's a script:

```
from functools import cached_property
from collections.abc import Callable

from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any, overload, Union


T = TypeVar("T")


class result_property(cached_property, Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[Any], T]) -> None:
        super().__init__(func)

    def __set_name__(self, owner: type[Any], name: str) -> None:
        super().__set_name__(owner, name)

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: Union[type[Any], None] = None) -> 'result_property[T]': ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: object, owner: Union[type[Any], None] = None) -> T: ...

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return super().__get__(instance, owner)


def func_str(s: str) -> None:
    print(s)


class Foo:
    @result_property
    def prop_int(self) -> int:
        return 1


foo = Foo()
func_str(foo.prop_int)  # type error is expected here
```

PyCharm types checker reports it's correct. However I except it reports a type error on the last line.
If I run mypy check on this script, it reports:

```
tmp.py:38: error: Argument 1 to "func_str" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Why Pycharm reports it's ok?
Is it possible to somehow modify the script for PyCharm to report type error in this situation as well?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently PyCharm hardcodes the logics of the name `cached_property` in its static type checker instead of inferring typing of a decorated method via a proper type inference system. It can be something entirely bogus and PyCharm would still use the same logics as long as it's named `cached_property`:

```
def cached_property(func):
    def foo(self):
        pass
    return foo

def func_str(s: str) -> None:
    print(s)

class Foo:
    @cached_property
    def prop_int(self) -> int:
        return 1

foo = Foo()
func_str(foo.prop_int) # PyCharm complains: Expected type 'str', got 'int' instead
```

So in order for your own descriptor to be treated like a `cached_property` you would simply have to name it `cached_property` in order for PyCharm to type check:

```
import functools

class cached_property(functools.cached_property, Generic[T]):
    ... # definition omitted

def func_str(s: str) -> None:
    print(s)

class Foo:
    @cached_property
    def prop_int(self) -> int:
        return 1

foo = Foo()
func_str(foo.prop_int) # PyCharm complains: Expected type 'str', got 'int' instead
```

It's not ideal, but will have to do until PyCharm stops taking shortcuts by hardcoding typing logics based on hardcoded names, and implements logically inferred typing for descriptors.

Comment: Ugh, Pycharm used to be a must have for me when writing Python, back when type hinting was not as common. Using "short cuts" like the names of functions to infer typing was the most pragmatic way to attempt analysis. But lately, the community is becoming more geared towards statically analyzable code, and many of the once necessary short cuts are just starting to get in the way. Honestly, at this point I think they need to really redo their Python analysis from scratch... maybe aligning more heavily with one of mypy or pyright.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked with a PyCharm 2023.2.5, and I get no error, even when trying a more complex version of your class, like enhancing type hinting in the `result_property` class to provide PyCharm more information:

```py
from functools import cached_property
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any, Union, cast

T = TypeVar("T")


class result_property(cached_property, Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[Any], T]) -> None:
        super().__init__(func)

    def __set_name__(self, owner: type[Any], name: str) -> None:
        super().__set_name__(owner, name)

    def __get__(self, instance: Any, owner: Union[type[Any], None] = None) -> Union[T, 'result_property[T]']:
        if instance is None:
            return self
        result = super().__get__(instance, owner)
        return cast(T, result)


def func_str(s: str) -> None:
    print(s)


class Foo:
    @result_property
    def prop_int(self) -> int:
        return 1


foo = Foo()
func_str(foo.prop_int)  # Hoping PyCharm reports a type error here
```

Given that PyCharm still does not report a type error even after enhancing the type hints, I suppose PyCharm's type inference system has limitations or behaves differently when handling complex scenarios like yours, involving custom decorators and generics. That discrepancy between PyCharm and [`mypy`](https://mypy-lang.org/) is not uncommon, especially in more complex or nuanced typing situations.

So your options, at this point, are:

- Use `mypy` or other static type checkers as part of your development workflow. Running mypy as a separate step in your testing or build process can help catch these types of errors, even if PyCharm does not.
  You can [install it in PyCharm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11086-mypy).
- Report this as an issue or feature request to [JetBrains' issue tracker for PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

As a (non-ideal) workaround, consider adjusting your code structure if this type-checking issue is important for your project. Sometimes, simplifying the code or avoiding overly complex typing constructs can make it more compatible with various type checkers.

Comment: Note: I tried and udated PyCharm to 2023.1: same result, no error.